# COMPLEX PARSE.com ISSUE! Query data and export into CSV with a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, parse-platform, export-to-excel

I am having issues getting an array into a CSV file, I can get the output into the CSV file now, however it is only printing the following into the CSV file:

```
objectId    createdAt
Array   Array
Array   Array
Array   Array
Array   Array
Array   Array
Array   Array
Array   Array
```

I believe it is because I need to flatten the array, but am at a loss on how to do it, I am pretty much picking up how to work with arrays & parse.com as I go, I do however have good knowledge of PHP, My code is as follows:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Counts");

 $results = $query->find();
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) 

 {    
    $detail=array();
    $object = $results[$i];

    $detail['objectId'][$i] = $object->getObjectId();
    $detail['createdAt'][$i] = $object->getCreatedAt();
  //  print_r($detail);
    $response[]=$detail;

 }


$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
header("Content-Type:application/csv"); 
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=dboutput.csv"); 
fputcsv($output, array('objectId','createdAt'));
foreach ($response as $fields) {
    fputcsv($output, $detail);
}
fclose($output);
```

instead of it outputting Array I need it to output the stored information, which is stored in my parse.com DB (createdAt = date & objectId = string).

If it helps the array looks like the following:

Array
(
    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => eGocH6OznC
        )

```
[createdAt] => Array
    (
        [0] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-12-11 23:02:03.968000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

    )
```

)
Array
(
    [date] => Array
        (
            [1] => P3uhKFzpsq
        )

```
[createdAt] => Array
    (
        [1] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2015-12-11 23:16:55.633000
                [timezone_type] => 2
                [timezone] => Z
            )

    )
```

)

I need to get just the Date value & objectId value into 2 columns of a CSV file.

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code for doing this is:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("Counts");

$results = $query->find();
$detail=array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++)

{

$object = $results[$i];

$detail[$i]['objectId'] = $object->getObjectId();
$detail[$i]['createdAt'] = $object->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

}


$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
header("Content-Type:application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=dboutput.csv");
fputcsv($output, array('objectId','createdAt'));
foreach ($detail as $fields) {
fputcsv($output, $fields);
}
fclose($output);

?>
```